# C++ template usage: change variable place leads to compilation error

Tags: c++, linux, templates, compilation, clang

I've got a simple program like this:

$cat testCompile.cpp

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int fd[2];
    template<int fd[]>
    void f(){printf("fd\n");}
    int main(){
        f<fd>();
        return 0;
    }
```

Compile and run it, no problem, it just prints "fd". But if I change the location of fd[2] into main function then it fails to compile:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    template<int fd[]>
    void f(){printf("fd\n");}
    int main(){
        int fd[2];
        f<fd>();
        return 0;
    }
```

clang reports:

```
    testCompile.cpp:6:5: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
        f<fd>();
        ^~~~~
    testCompile.cpp:3:6: note: candidate template ignored: invalid
          explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'fd'
    void f(){printf("fd\n");}
         ^
    1 error generated.
```

What does this error indicates? Anything wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to remember that templates is a compile-time thing, it's all handled by the compiler and nothing is done at run-time.

Then you need to remember that the most common handling of local variables is to put them on the stack, and the location of the stack may not be known at the time of compilation.

Now if we put it all together, because the location of stack-allocated objects are not known at the time of compilation, only at run-time, you can't have stack-allocated (i.e. local variables) used with templates.

It works for global variables because then the compiler can know the actual location of the object.

Comment: I think templates are instantiated based on the datatype of the object not by the location of the object. If that is being the case then there is no difference between local variable and global variable.

Comment: i see, it will spit error because it will be no way to find where the local variables is allocated in the memory, but i dont understand about global variables.

Comment: @PremkumarU Templates can have non-type arguments, to pass values at compile-time. In this example a pointer is passed as the template argument, so in the function `fd` is not a type but a pointer to `int`. Much like if it was passed as a normal function argument.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez On most modern systems the stack is provided by the operating system when the program starts, that's why the location can't be known by the compiler. But the location for global and `static` variables will have a fixed location that is set by the compiler and linker, which is why the compiler will know their locations and can use it for template arguments.

Comment: @n.m. No worries :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude got it, but what would that location be if its not in the stack?

Comment: @LorenceHernandez When the compiler and linker creates a program, it splits the program and the executable into four parts: Data segment (which have global and `static` initialized variables), a BSS segment (which have global and `static` uninitialized variables), a text segment (which have the code, plus string literals), and finally the stack (which is not stored in the executable file). Besides the stack, all those segments have fixed locations (addresses ) in (virtual) memory.